# Want to fetch methods using AST in java using eclipse libraries

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist, hashmap

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Expression;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IMethodBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation;


public class Test {

    static BufferedReader in;

    public static void main(String a[]){

        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);

        File file = new File("F:\\Jalil\\projects\\AST\\src\\MethodInvocation.java");

        try {

            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        try {
            while (null != (line = in.readLine())) {

                buffer.append("\t" + line);
                buffer.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        parser.setSource(buffer.toString().toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);

        final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        System.out.println(cu.imports().get(0));

        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {

                if (node.getName().getIdentifier().equals("testSearch")) {

                    Block block = node.getBody();

                    block.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

                        public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {

                            System.out.println("Name: " + node.getName());

                            Expression expression = node.getExpression();

                            if (expression != null) {

                                System.out.println("Expr: " + expression.toString());

                                ITypeBinding typeBinding = expression.resolveTypeBinding();

                                if (typeBinding != null) {

                                    System.out.println("Type: " + typeBinding.getName());
                                }
                            }

                            IMethodBinding binding = node.resolveMethodBinding();

                            if (binding != null) {

                                ITypeBinding type = binding.getDeclaringClass();

                                if (type != null) {

                                    System.out.println("Decl: " + type.getName());
                                }
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to fetch all the methods from the java source file from the file i put in code but in out put me only getting 1 import of import java.util.ArrayList.
Kindly help me out in it i want to fetch all the imports, methods its name types and declaration.